# How to install a downloaded .deb file

Tags: command-line

I am new to Ubuntu. I installed a Ubuntu a few days back. I downloaded a deb files. But i don't know how to install it. Can anyone tell me how to install a downloaded deb file?

Comment: just an FYI, installing the .deb file directly will require you to manually install updates... you won't get these update notifications automatically, and hence this is not the preferred means of installation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Terminal and type below commands

To Install a downloaded .deb file:

```
sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
```

To Remove a Installed package:

```
sudo dpkg -r packagename
```

Answer (score 3):

`sudo dpkg -i /path/to/your.deb` or use GDebi.

More info can be found on the [wiki about installing software](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Installing_downloaded_packages).